# Comprobar si una string contiene una substring que a su vez está contenida en otra string (Java)

Tags: java, string, substring

Quiero comprobar si una cadena de texto contiene una secuencia que a su vez está contenida en otra cadena, es decir, el comportamiento deseado sería:

```
String cadena1 = "Rojo característico";
String cadena2 = "Rojo chillón";

public boolean contieneSubstringContenidaEn(String cadena1, String cadena2) {
    // Calcular variable booleana condición.
    if (condicion) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

boolean contiene = contieneSubstringContenidaEn(cadena1, cadena2);
System.out.println(contiene);
```

---

```
>true
```

¿Cuál es la forma más eficiente de hacerlo?

Comment: Por qué usas el `String.valueOf()` para asignar el boolean, si tu método ya devuelve booleanos? Y la manera más eficiente de hacerlo... es como lo estás haciendo, imagino. Simplemente tendrás que usar `indexOf(str)`. Si necesitas comprobarlo dos veces, no veo manera de hacerlo que no sea comprobando dos veces, a no ser que quieras saltarte la primera comprobación. Por ejemplo si tienes "ha" y "ha de" y "ha de estar", en realidad basta con comprobar si "ha de" está en "ha de estar", porque si es así, "ha" también va a estar ahí. Con una única llamada lo tienes

Comment: ¿Hay una longitud mínima para la intersección? Es decir, los Strings `"rojo chillón"` y `"verde"` tienen una secuencia común: `"r"`

Comment: Por cierto... un método `void` no devuelve nada!

Comment: @Benito-B Modificado gracias

Comment: @Pablo Lozano No había caído en eso.

Comment: Imagino que no hay manera más sencilla de hacerlo que decir, mi color de menor longitud tiene longitud cuatro, hacer todas las posibles substrings de cuatro hasta cadena.lenght para ambas cadenas y comprobar si hay coincidencia. (??)

Comment: No para ambas cadenas. Puedes en un bucle ir leyendo 4 caracteres de la primera cadena. Osea, en la primera iteración lees los 4 primeros (del 0 al 3), en la segunda del 1 al 4, en la tercera del 2 al 5,... y así hasta llegar a los últimos 4 caracteres. En cada iteración, compruebas si los 4 caracteres son substring de la segunda cadena. En caso afirmativo, devuelves true. Si llegas a salir del bucle, es que no se ha encontrado ninguna substring, de forma que devuelves false. No es complicado.

Comment: Ah, ten en cuenta también si quieres comparar teniendo en cuenta o no las mayúsculas.

Comment: Luego tendrás que afinarlo, por ejemplo cuando cojas 4 caracteres hazle trim para eliminar espacios en blanco del principio y del final, y se te queda más corta (porque ha eliminado algún espacio) entonces ya no tiene longitud de 4 y no hace falta que compruebes si es substring, pasas a la siguiente iteración. Eso entendiendo que lo que quieres buscar como substring siempre va a ser una palabra (sin espacios).

Comment: @José Carlos PHP Sí tengo una base de datos de minerales y pregunto en un quiz por color con cuatro opciones. Quiero que si la correcta es "Rojo chillón", no se incluyan entre los minerales incorrectos los que tengan de color "Rojo característico" porque ambos contienen el color rojo. Muchas gracias, ahora me pongo a ello y pongo la respuesta si lo logro hacer funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí va mi propuesta:

```
public static boolean contieneSubstringContenidoEn( String str1, String str2 ) {
    boolean isContained = false; 
    String [] words = str1.replace(",", "").split(" "); 
    for( String word : words ) {
        if( str2.toLowerCase().contains( word.toLowerCase() ) ) {
            isContained = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isContained;
}
```

Supongo que por "contenido" se refiere a que "una palabra del primer string debe estar al menos en el segundo string". Basado en esta premisa, separo en palabras el primer string (omito posibles comas que distorisionarían el resultado) y busco la palabra en cuestión en el string de destino.

Comment: Se me había olvidado el break gracias por responder.

Comment: Se puede hacer sin el break también: sencillamente retornando justo en ese punto

Comment: He usado tu método, gracias. Lo único que he tenido que hacer un replace(".","") porque algunos tienen "Rojo.".